# Correct way to handle compiler flags when using CMake

Tags: cmake, compiler-flags, build-system

I am struggling to find a proper way to propagate correct compiler flags for all targets.

Let's imagine that there is a project which contains a library and unit tests.

```
ProjectFolder
|-WorkerLibFolder
  |-Worker.cpp
  |-Worker.hpp
  |-CMakeLists.txt  (2)
|-main.cpp
|-CMakeLists.txt (1)
|-TestsFolder
  |-UnitTests.cpp
  |-CMakeLists.txt  (3)
```

In CMakeLists.txt (1) I'd like to set compile options globally because I assume that optimization level and other flags should be the same for all libraries of the project. 
`add_compile_options(-Wall -Werror -Wno-error=maybe-uninitialized)` is used to achieve it.

Also I use `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` feature which automatically sets needed optimization level with help of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` or `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` flags.

Also the fact that afterwards one of these variables is implicitly passed to the compiler seems to be annoying, becaues I anyway have to set these variables in advance for needed optimization flags `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-Ofast -DNDEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS")` only because `-O3` is by defaut set with Release configuration.

Anyway everything is ok up to the moment when I want to alway have `-O0` being set when compiling test environment (UniTests.cpp). CMakeLists.txt (3) produces project_ut executable. I want WorkerLib to be compiled with configured optimization level (taked from `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`), but it automatically means that `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` with `-Ofast` is propagated to UnitTest.cpp

I guess that I might be doing something strange here and there is a better way to deal with an issue.
One option here is to pass optimization flags without help of `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` feature but it seems to be a wrong (as I do not want to maintain lists of flags for every target).

EDIT:

```
#CMakeLists.txt(1):
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.1)
project(TestProject LANGUAGES CXX C)

#####  common comp flags #####

add_compile_options(-Wall -Werror -Wno-error=maybe-uninitialized)

##############################

set(RELEASE_FLAGS "-Ofast -DNDEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS")
set(DEBUG_FLAGS "-O0 -ggdb3")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ${RELEASE_FLAGS})
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE ${RELEASE_FLAGS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG ${DEBUG_FLAGS})
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG ${DEBUG_FLAGS})

add_subdirectory(WorkerLibFolder)
add_subdirectory(TestsFolder)


add_executable(mainExec main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mainExec PRIVATE worker)
```

```
#CMakeLists.txt(3):
add_executable(tests UnitTests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tests PRIVATE worker)
#I want sommehow fix optimization flags for that particular target, while for worker library left them as they were set
```

```
#CMakeLists.txt(2):
add_library(worker Worker.cpp)
target_include_directories(worker PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
```

Comment: It would be way-way cleaner rather then _describing_ what you do, to _show_ the actual CMakeLists.txt sources..

Comment: Agreed, it is difficult to decipher what it going on here based on the description. A minimal example would be much cleaner, and easier to understand.

Comment: That's a good point, I added an example. Initially I somehow thought that description would be more preferable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The proper way to set flags is with `set_compile_options` and `target_compile_options` and macros with `add_compile_definitions` and `target_compile_definitions`. You should not (or rarely) touch `CMAKE_*_FLAGS` yourself and with the creation of generator expressions, you rarely should touch `CMAKE_*_FLAGS_*`, too. Using `$<CONFIG:RELEASE>` is simpler, because you don't need to care about case (`-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` and `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=rElEaSe` are both release builds) and for my eyes much cleaner to read.

Do in your main `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_compile_options(
       -Wall -Werror -Wno-error=maybe-uninitialized
       $<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-Ofast>
       $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-O0>
       $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-ggdb3>
)
add_compile_definitions(
        $<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:NDEBUG>
        $<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS>
)
add_subdirectory(WorkerLibFolder)
add_subdirectory(TestsFolder)
add_executable(main ...)
```

> I want to alway have -O0 being set when compiling test environment

So do exactly that. Inside `TestsFolder` do:

```
add_compile_options(-O0)
add_library(test_environment  ....)
```

Or better:

```
add_library(test_environment ..
target_compile_options(test_environment PRIVATE -O0)
```

Because compile options are accumulated, the options added in `TestsFolder` will be suffixed/the last options on the compile line so it will work, I mean ex. `gcc -O3 -Ofast -O0` will compile the same as `gcc -O0`.

> target_include_directories(worker PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

The `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` is usually used from `include(this_files)` files to indicate from where the file is. To include current directory the `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` is more commonly used which, well, indicates the current source directory cmake is processing.

PS: I wouldn't unittest a program/library with different optimize options then the release is build with. I unittest with exactly the same compile options as the release builds. Some bugs show up only with optimizations enabled. The way I preferably unittest a (previous) library is to compile and unittest with both optimization disabled and enabled.

Comment: I tried to use what you suggested and it works and looks nice to me, though I have some comments: 1) compilation command now looks a bit strange: `-O3 -DNDEBUG   -Wall -Werror -Wno-error=maybe-uninitialized -Ofast`  for Worker library and `-O3 -DNDEBUG   -Wall -Werror -Wno-error=maybe-uninitialized -Ofast -O0 ` for UnitTest executable. It's a pitty I cannot get rid of initial O3 & Ofast (Release build). 2) Optimization level is set only for test environment. I had to do it as there are some huge test data vectors and it takes ages to compile them in Release.

Comment: 1) Yes. Sadly the `add_compile_options` and `target_compile_options` are append-only. There are some cmake scripts I've seen online to remove compile options from (even existing) targets or sources, but it get's messy real quick. 2) Yes, the `target_compile_options` let's us to specifically list compile options for each targets. Was that your intention to set optimization only for test environment?

Comment: regarding point 2: as my test environment libraries are placed in a separate directory then I thought that `add_compile_options` can deal with it. But actually now I'm think of creating two function like `set_common_compile_options(target_name)` and `set_common_compile_options_for_test_env(target_name)` and call them for every target I have (the only drawback here I think is that I have to remember about calling this function each time).

Comment: There's a typo here. `$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>-O0>` should be `$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-O0>`. Same for the `-ggdb3` one.

Answer (score 1):

There are several recent best practices ([here](https://github.com/boost-cmake/bcm/wiki/Cmake-best-practices-and-guidelines), [here](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/#leave-cmake_cxx_flags-alone) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eC9-iRN2b04)) that suggest your `CMakeLists.txt` should be clean and flexible.

I would suggest moving those flags externally (i.e. not placed in your `CMakeLists.txt`), by keeping them in related bash scripts, e.g.

```
C_FLAGS=""
C_FLAGS="${C_FLAGS} -Wall"
C_FLAGS="${C_FLAGS} -g -gline-tables-only"

LINKER_FLAGS=""

BUILD_TYPE=Debug

#

cmake \
  -GNinja \
  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ \
  -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0056=NEW \
  -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=On \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${BUILD_TYPE} \
  -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="${C_FLAGS}" \
  -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="${LINKER_FLAGS}" \
  -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="${LINKER_FLAGS}" \
  -DCMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS="${LINKER_FLAGS}" \
  "${SRC_DIR}"
```

This way you can have sets of flags for what you are trying to do.

A next step would be to allow for generator expressions and configure per target for specific options per build type, but it is hard to suggest without seeing an example from your `CMakeLists.txt`.

You could even have project-specific CMake variables that can be influenced and used per target, but that might be too complicated for your project.

Comment: Probably I should pay more attention to generator expresions after all and not creating external flag sets in an additional script. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @NwMan you should use them in combination. no weird compilation commands here. you'll be able to build a lot of stuff without hardcoding options in your CMake file, which is a CMake "[smell](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/#leave-cmake_cxx_flags-alone)" and also follows best [practice](https://github.com/boost-cmake/bcm/wiki/Cmake-best-practices-and-guidelines). So, the script file I propose is just for convenience and keeping your CMake file clean.